# Background fit LinearLayout

Tags: android, background

I want the background picture not to be deformed, but everytime I try, `ImageView` appears in front of other UI elements.

I already tried with an image view `android:src` and `scaleType=center`, 
and when I try with another layout, then I can't make the picture fit.

Comment: Can you post some pics of what you have and what you want to achieve?

Comment: set the image as the background of the parent `ViewGroup` and set `alpha` on it..

Answer (score 0):

try settings `scaleType=matrix`, if that didnt help either then there is issues with intrinsic padding , i will post customImageview Then.
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/xxxx"
        android:src="@drawable/xxxx" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/xxxx"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/today"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="xxx"
                android:textSize="xxsp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```